# If where clause matches, get last corresponding entry and match

Tags: sql-server

Please see [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cdf5bc/1) for structure.

```
CREATE TABLE batches
    ([batchId] varchar(20), [batch] varchar(20), [partId] varchar(10), [status] varchar(1), [ts] datetime,)
;

INSERT INTO batches
    ([batchId], [batch], [partId],[status], [ts])
VALUES
    ('1', '4711','CCC', 'A', '2020-09-01 00:00:00.000'),
    ('2', '4711','DDD','P', '2020-10-15 03:00:12.000'),
    ('3', '4711','XKF2','F', '2020-10-20 22:31:00.000'),
    ('4', '4712', '0000','P', '2020-10-14 23:01:24.000'),
    ('5', '4713', 'CCC','A', '2020-10-15 00:00:00.000'),
    ('6', '4713', 'CCC','F', '2020-10-05 00:00:00.000'),
    ('7', '4714', 'FSF','P', '2020-10-15 22:10:00.000')
;
```

Some Information: This is a database which contains batches. Each batch has a batchnumber (called `[batch]`)
which connects its complete chain together because for one batch, there are (multiple) unique (`[batchId]`) entries.
so you can review a history of a given batchnumber, like what happened with it.

So, now I need a query which returns **the last status of the batchnumber** (`[batch]`) and the `[partId]` of the matched unique batch entry, **when one of its unique batch entries
matches this**: `ts between 2020-10-14 22:00:00:00 and 2020-10-15 22:00:00:00 and status = 'P'`

expected resultset would be `partId:DDD status: F and partId:0000 status:P`

(bold is expected result combination)

('1', '4711','CCC', 'A', '2020-09-01 00:00:00.000'),

('2', '4711','**DDD**','P', '2020-10-15 03:00:12.000'),

('3', '4711','XKF2','**F**', '2020-10-20 22:31:00.000'),

('4', '4712', '**0000**','**P**', '2020-10-14 23:01:24.000'),

My approach is this, but its not working, any ideas?

```
SELECT
  a.partId, c.status
FROM
  batches a
 join (select max(b.ts) as 'ts', b.batch, b.status from batches b group by b.batch, b.status) c on c.batch=a.batch
 where
 a.ts between '2020-10-14 22:00:00' and '2020-10-15 22:00:00' and a.status ='P'
 group by a.partId, c.status
```

Comment: `see sql fiddle for structure` - please always put ALL info into the question as well, so that if you remove the fiddle, or if SQLFiddle goes out of business, the question is still complete.

Comment: Your (described) time range is from Oct 14 22:00 to Oct 14 22:00, but your SQL shows 14th to 15th. Just want to check that.

Comment: oh, thank you, updated it

Comment: Is it possible to have more than record with a `P` status in the date range, and if so what part number would you want to see?

Comment: Yes. I want to see the partId from the first entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` windowing function to greatly simplify this:

```
select b3.*
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by b1.[batch] order by [ts] desc) rn
    from batches b1
    where [batch] in (
       select distinct [batch] 
       from batches b2
       where b2.ts between '2020-10-14 22:00:00' and '2020-10-15 22:00:00' and b2.status ='P'
     )
) b3
where rn = 1
```

See it work here:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cdf5bc/94/0

---

Here's an alternative using a `JOIN` rather than an `IN()`:

```
select b3.*
from (
    select b1.*, row_number() over (partition by b1.[batch] order by [ts] desc) rn
    from batches b1
    inner join (
       select distinct [batch] 
       from batches b2
       where b2.ts between '2020-10-14 22:00:00' and '2020-10-15 22:00:00' and b2.status ='P'
    ) b3 on b3.[batch] = b1.[batch]
) b3
where rn = 1
```

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cdf5bc/98/0

The `row_number()` solutions should also run faster than the extra `JOIN`s.

Note the `partID` here doesn't match with the expected results in the question, but *the expected results of the question also don't match up with the problem statement.*

---

Here's a query that will at least show you this other part number:

```
select b4.*
from (
    select b1.*, b3.partId as OtherPart
        , row_number() over (partition by b1.[batch] order by [ts] desc) rn
    from batches b1
    inner join (
       select [batch], partID
          , row_number() over (partition by [batch] order by [ts]) rn
       from batches b2
       where b2.ts between '2020-10-14 22:00:00' and '2020-10-15 22:00:00' and b2.status ='P'
    ) b3 on b3.[batch] = b1.[batch] and b3.rn = 1
) b4
where rn = 1
```

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cdf5bc/102/0

However, keep in mind *it's almost always a mistake to mix values from different rows* like this. In this case, there was never a record for part `DDD` with that status or timestamp, but these results could give someone the impression there was.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close. You want the max date for each batch, so you need to join to each batch & ts instead of just the batch

```
SELECT d.PartID, b.Status
FROM (--find newest status for each batch
      SELECT batch, Max(ts) AS ts
      FROM batches a
      GROUP BY batch
     ) a
  join ( --find all batches who had status='P' within the date range
        SELECT batch, Max(ts) AS ts
        FROM batches 
        WHERE a.ts between '2020-10-14 22:00:00' and '2020-10-15 22:00:00'
          AND a.status ='P'
        GROUP BY batch
  ) c on c.batch=a.batch -- filter
  -- need one more join to get [status] from the newest run of the batch
  join batches b on a.batch=b.batch and a.ts=b.ts
  -- and one more to get Part ID from the filtered set
  join batches d on c.batch=d.batch and c.ts=d.ts
```

The awkward part is getting the newest `Status` for older batches. `Status` can't go into a GROUP BY, so it has to be attached outside of another GROUP BY.

The last join will prevent duplicates, if there are multiple records with `status='P'` within the date range.

Comment: thank you for that hint, helped! Unfortunately it is not yet entirely correct.
The result I get gives me the wrong status for **"DDD"**. I expect status "F" but i get status "P" (I always need the status from the **LAST** entry of that batch)
[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cdf5bc/50)

`SELECT
  a.partId, c.status
FROM
  batches a
 join (select max(b.ts) as 'ts', b.batch, b.status from batches b group by b.batch, b.status) c 
 on c.batch=a.batch and a.ts = c.ts
 where
 a.ts between '2020-10-14 22:00:00' and '2020-10-15 22:00:00' and a.status ='P'
 group by a.partId, c.status
 `

Comment: ...as an addition, result should be: `partId` from the first entry that has the given `status`and the `status` from the `last`entry of that batch-history

Comment: Okay. Now I think I get it. You want the *newest* row for any Batch who had a status of P within the given date range.  You don't want the data from the date range, you want the newest.

Comment: I want the row which has a status of P within the date range. From that row, I need the `partId`. From the newest row **for that batch**, I need the `status` so the result for batch `4711`would be `partId: DDD` (that matches the were clause) and `status: F` (that matches the join, so the newest entry for that batch)

Comment: Thats why I pick the partId from `A` and the `status`from `C` because how I understand it, the join should return the `newest` entry for the batch, which should contain the correct status which is `F` in my example. I do not understand why its not working like this.

Comment: Ok. It needs one more GROUP BY.  See modifications.

Comment: Thanks mate, will check it tomorrow! Ill let you know if it worked